# CMOS in a switched capacitor

Tags: cmos, switched-capacitor

If CMOS is used in a switched capacitor circuit, is it possible to ensure that the pair of switches are break-before-make?  I'm specifically considering the wiring of the CD4007 CMOS transistor array illustrated in the Appendix of [https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/alm1k/alm-signals-labs/alm-switched-cap-filter-lab?s[]=switched](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/alm1k/alm-signals-labs/alm-switched-cap-filter-lab?s%5B%5D=switched) .  When the pulses applied to pins 3 and 10 appear as shown below, then the pair of nMOS connections between pins 9 and 12 and between pins 5 and 4 are break-before-make, but the pair of pMOS connections between pins 1 and 2 and between pins 12 and 11 are make-before-break.  When the illustrated pulses are inverted so overlap at logic 1, then the situations for the nMOS and pMOS are exchanged, so in every case, the circuit is make-before-break.  I'm assuming here that the signal has a small enough amplitude and is biased such that the pMOS switches close when their gates are at pulse low and the nMOS switches close when their gates are at pulse high.

So, the circuit will only work if the clock sources are perfect inverses and the MOS has no switching delay.  Can these requirements be adequately satisfied?  My understanding is that use of CMOS helps with linearity by minimizing variation of r_D as the signal level varies, but given the near impossibility of break-before-make switching, is CMOS really worth it?  I could just use the nMOS devices at the expense of linearity.

[image: Non-overlapping clocks]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.